# Facebook application for Bot working only for admin or developer not publicly

Tags: facebook, botframework, messenger

I have Facebook page for company and for contact on messenger and on page we are using FB application that is linked to Bot  microsoft bot framework.

That same FB application is public and available, but Bot is not responding to anyone except to application **Admin** or **Developer**.

Comment: Did you submit the necessary things for review?

Comment: Have you contacted facebook support? That would probably be a good place to start if your app has already been approved by Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to request the Send API (Pages Messaging) to be approved for your bot. You can do this via the Facebook App dashboard- Products- settings, and a tester will check the questions and answers you provide.

This is a common problem, and one that I face also. Since you assume that setting your bot outside of development mode and available to the public it will automatically be live.